# При получение первого символа, получаю знак вопроса

Tags: php

Если быть точнее, то символ выглядит именно так �.

То есть задача простая, получить у имени первый символ.

```
$a = 'Дима';
echo $a[0];
```

Пробовал через функции, вдруг так лучше, подумал я.
Использовал `substr`, но не помогло.

Именно имя полностью, без обрезки. Будет выводиться корректно.
Но получая первый символ - не работает.

В шапке стоит мета тег.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Бд также - `utf8_general_ci`.

Пробовал добавлять в php.

`header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Но также результатов не дало.
И при этом если идут английские буквы. То работает правильно.

Comment: скорее всего, это из-за того, что русские символы кодируются двумя байтами, а php по дефолту работает как с однобайтовой кодировкой.
Попробуйте:
echo mb_substr($a, 0, 1);
PS В PHP должен быть установлен модуль mbstring

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: отметьте как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего, это из-за того, что русские символы кодируются двумя байтами, а php по дефолту работает как с однобайтовой кодировкой. Попробуйте: echo mb_substr($a, 0, 1); PS В PHP должен быть установлен модуль mbstring